# Punctuating "Did you wonder"

Tags: questions, punctuation

Would this have a question mark? (This is a lead sentence)

> Did you ever wonder how thunderstorms are formed or what happens during a thunderstorm.

Comment: If it's a question, it should end with a question mark. Not having a question mark would make it a statement, but you can't make a statement that begins with "Did you ever wonder" as there's no way to end it with something factual.

Answer (score 5):

Of course. "Did", when used at the start of a sentence, is an **interrogative word** - a word whose function is to form a question.

So, yes, you need a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

This is asking whether the reader ever wondered how thunderstorms are formed or what happens during a thunderstorm, and therefore, the correct punctuation is a question mark.

Comment: This is a good start to an answer, but *why* is this a question? *What* makes it a question? You'd have a very solid answer if you addressed these key points :)

Comment: @Dog Lover Solid? This is an inappropriate question for ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe so, but that shouldn't mean that it can't be respected nonetheless and be given a helpful answer.